# C# Using T4 to generate enums

Tags: c#, t4

In my project I'd like to use T4 to generate my enums. To test this, I created a test project with a simple form. In this project I added a .tt file and put my code into that file.

Everything works, but I was a little bit disappointed. I thought that when the project gets executed, the T4 generates the enumeration. So the enumeration is always uptodate. But this ain't the case, right? If you want the enumeration to be updated, you have to do this manually and rebuild your solution. My question is, am I correct in this one? Or did I miss something.

Second, why should I use T4 to create an enum? I mean if the enum changes I have to rebuild my solution.

EDIT:
I get my enum values from a database table. The table only has 2 fields: Id and Description

Comment: "why should I use T4 to create an enum?"  That's an excellent question.  Where are you getting the enum values that you wish to generate?

Comment: I get my enum values from the database (I've edited my startpost)

Comment: So how else would it work *other* than that it only updates when you rebuild your solution?  How would the T4 template "know" that your database has changed and thus needs to update?

Comment: I was thinking it is more powerful if the Enum is generated by every startup. This way the solution doesn't need a rebuild and the enum is always up to date. But if this isn't possible, then why use T4 to generate an enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I don't believe it is worth the effort. You still have to go back and update your code to handle any new values. The best thing you can do is make sure you have a default case for your switch statements.

```
switch (enumValue)
{
    // ...
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "The enum value " + enumValue + " is unhandled."
        );
}
```

Comment: This is more a workaround, but thanks for the effort though :)

Comment: @Martijn - Not quite a workaround, more like advice. My point being that using a template to regenerate your enum really doesn't save you much time. You need to manually handle the new values at every place you use the enum.

Answer (score 2):

### Your table isn't an actual `enum` equivalent

If your table changes it's values it isn't really a good contender to become an `enum` now is it? C# enumerations tend to be statically defined and don't change unless there's a reason for that. And when they do, code has to adopt to this change to use additional values.

So if your application is able to change table's content than this is just a usual table.

But in case you want a generic T4 template that actually does generate enumeration with XML documentation and all I've put some effort into writing such a template. Everything is well documented in [this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html). Including template's code.

Comment: Lookup tables are supposed to be static, but a requirement may come where you will add entries or remove them. Something perfectly plausible and even expected in IT, in my opinion. So yes, the source data for a conversion to enums should not be something that is changed on a regular basis, but it is almost impractical to assume a source will not change.

Comment: By the way, exactly today I ended up in [your blog] (http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.il/), after some googling, very good caption/introduction :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on going the other direction (generating a c# enum from the SQL view)

http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/t4-template-for-generating-sql-view-from-csharp-enumeration/

Answer (score 0):

[PLINQO](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks/plinqo/tour/enums) is able to generated enums from one table quite easily but you'd be stuck with LINQ-TO-SQL. Good enough if you only need the generated enums though!